# How to install xorg inside virtualbox guest?

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, software-installation, virtualbox

I am fairly new to Arch linux so I want to install it inside a VM first before replacing my current Linux installation.

I've successfully installed `base`, `base-devel` & `grub` packages inside a virtualbox vm. I can successfully login to the newly installed system.

I am a bit confused as I cannot get the xorg working.
I've installed the following packages:

```
#pacman -S xorg-server xorg-xinit xorg-server-utils mesa
#pacman -S xorg-twm xorg-xclock xterm
```

I have selected all the default selection for driver choice.
Following is the error log when I run `startx`:
[image: error]

Here is the log: `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`:
[image]
 Is there any specific package which I need to install in order to successfully `startx` inside a virtualbox guest VM?

Comment: `(EE) Fatal server error: (EE) no screens found (EE) Pklease consult the X Org Foundation support`
`xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused`

Comment: I will update the question for more clarity

Comment: @Mat I've updated the question. Please have a look

Comment: `Please consult the log file at "/var/..." for additional information`

Comment: What video card do you have?

Comment: I am running in inside a Virtual box VM, I am not sure if the host video card will matter in this case. It is some intel based video card (not nvidia/ATI)

Comment: did you try this [method](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinitrc#Configuration) from Arch Linux wiki?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install the full xorg, plus virtualbox support (you might have to reboot after that):
`pacman -S xorg virtualbox-guest-utils`
If you really want to use startx you need either to change your `~/.xinitrc`  to start `blackbox` or install ugly old `twm` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Installing `virtualbox-guest-utils` fixed the problem for me, however, my situation was a little different from OPs -- I'd run `systemctl enable lxdm.service`. Because I lacked the guest package, I saw a grainy, blue screen with no indication of the real problem.